# Extracting file name using os.path.basename returning mode and encoding along with filename

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am running following command to get the filename

```
rep = os.path.basename(path)
print(rep)
```

It is returning following additional details also which are not required.
`23-54-00__CreateKey__TCStatus_Report.html' mode='a+' encoding='cp1252'`

Anybody have any idea how to get only filename? Please Help!!!

Comment: Those additional details are presumably already in `path`.  How is the value of `path` set?

Comment: Is this the full output you're getting or just the additional details?

Comment: How is the `path` variable generated? What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

This looks an awful lot like the output of calling `str` on a file object:

```
>>> with open('foo', 'w') as f:
...     str(f)
... 
"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='foo' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>"
```

My guess is that somehow, the `path` variable ended up containing a file object instead of the file path. Then, getting its basename just converted the file object to a string using `str`, generating a representation like the one above, and spat out the portion after the last slash, which would be the tail end of the filename plus the mode and encoding portions.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately path variable was ending up containing file object and that's why it was printing additional details.
Resolved this issue by changing it to only file path.
Thank you so much!!!